# jQuery: template from string question

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Lets say I have a viewmodel like this

```
var viewModel = {
    "Dtos": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Number": 100,
        "Description": "some description",
        "Total": 200},
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Number": 200,
        "Description": "some description",
        "Total": 400}]
};

viewModel.EditUrl = "http://someUrl.com?Id=${Id}";
```

How can I render the EditUrl in a following template so that containing template processes it as a template; in other words how can I convert that string that is in the viewmodel to a template within template.

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="${EditUrl}">Edit</a></td>
            <td>${Id}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Knockout.js takes care of binding this, so Id renders properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you make viewModel.EditUrl a function like:

```
viewModel.EditUrl = function(id) { return "http://someUrl.com?Id=" + id; }
```

Then, your template would look like:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="${viewModel.EditUrl(Id)}">Edit</a></td>
            <td>${Id}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/CegbS/

Otherwise, since you are using knockout, you could consider making EditUrl a dependentObservable on each item in your array.  Then, you could actually bind to just EditUrl.  Pretty much the same as above, just the function would be on each item in the array.  Let me know and I could show you an example of that as well.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer: Cool, function would work, but I would prefer using observable. Can you post that example as well?

Comment: Would be something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KmVkA/ .  Moved the creation of a Dtos item to a function, just because when you start defining dependentObservables or other functions on each item it helps to streamline object creation in your viewModel definition.

Comment: @RP Niewmeyer: I accepted your answer, but it is not exactly what I needed. See, my viewModel comes as JSON from server, and I apply mapping plugin to it. I would prefer not to have to do any additional js functions on the client. I would like to be able to say that EditUrl is just a member on the viewmodel that template would know how to render. On the server side viewModel is just a dynamic type and users can type the url using the syntax above. If I start introducing javascript syntax it will not work :)

Comment: Can you just have your server-side return an EditUrl proeprty that is already properly formatted?  Otherwise, the mapping plug-in has some hooks to customize object creation.  Would it work for you if the EditUrl dependentObservable was created by the mapping plugin?  Let me know, I could try an example of that as well.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer: Here is a fiddle that is more realistic http://jsfiddle.net/epitka/HuNqP/3/  All of the markup comes from the server and is generated on the fly. I could precalculate urls, but that would mean that I would have to pass that for each item (dto), rather then just url that is basically a template. Does that make sense? http://jsfiddle.net/epitka/HuNqP/3/

Comment: @RP Niemeyer:I tried something like this ${$.tmpl($data.EditUrl, $data)} but it does not work :(

Comment: How about: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BhHTF/ .  Passed options into the mapping plugin, so that your Dtos items get the dependentObservables.  Left the "base" URLs on the root node of the viewModel, as you had them.

Comment: I think that mapping plug-in might be your best bet.  However, here is a sample using $.tmpl(viewModel.EditUrl, $data).text()  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7psE6/

Comment: @RP Niemeyer: Thanks RP very much for your help with this, I really appreciate it. This last solution would be the best, and I see it working in your fiddle, but it does not work in mine :) http://jsfiddle.net/epitka/HuNqP/4/ . I am leaning towards just resolving them ahead and adding them to each dto.

Comment: There is something strange about your fiddle.  This is just a copy of the code from your fiddle into a new one.  The resources look the same as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xJcpN/  Try forking off of this one.